# Changing a ListView to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I've just recently started to learn android and up until two days ago I didn't know what material design meant or that `RecyclerView` existed.
I've already implemented a list view on my app, though it's pretty basic and I should add features to it.
My question is: should I change my list to a `RecyclerView` even though the list is very limited in size, since every item is fully created by manual user's input? 
Let me add that I did read about the differences, even here bit for the following reasons I still have my dilemma:

1. As I said my list size will be limited by size, and since `RecyclerView` is all about recycling, is it really necessary here?

   2. Even though `RecyclerView` is "the future", I've seen it's missing features that `ListView` already has like items dividers and more, and I know these can still be implemented on RecyclerView, but is it worth the effort for my case?

Help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small limited list you can live with list view.If you don't need item animators, item decorators and layout managers you can live with list view.

Recycler view mandates the use of View Holder pattern which is not the case with list view.

The implementation of a recycler view is complex than that of list view.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, if I'd like to add item animators, decorators etc.. Would you recommend me to switch to RecyclerView even for a small list like mine?

Comment: RecyclerView isn't so complex, it just force us to use ViewHolder pattern. I changed all ListView in my app to RecyclerView. It is easier to apply animations with recycler view. Even if for small list, I recommend using recycler view. Also, ListView doesn't work with some new features in android support library.